# Negative of token in ANTLR4

Tags: java, escaping, antlr, token, antlr4

I define `LEGAL_ESCAPE` token like this:

```
LEGAL_ESCAPE: '\\'('b'|'f'|'r'|'n'|'t'|'"')?;
```

Is there any way for me to use negative of this token to define another `ILLEGAL_ESCAPE` token?

Comment: What do you mean by "negative" of the token? As in anything that is not that token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly:

```
LEGAL_ESCAPE    : ESC [bfrnt"] ;
ILLEGAL_ESCAPE  : ESC 
                   ( ~[bfrnt"]  // any char not in the set
                   | EOF        // it is a non char
                   )
                ;
fragment ESC    : '\\' ;
```

There are quite a few of these 'tricks' implicit in the various example grammars in the [Antlr4 Grammar Repo](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4). The abnf and less grammars are good starting points.  The Java8, Antlr4 and Python3 grammars demonstrate many of the more involved capabilities.

Note, the negation operator `~` works on characters, sets and ranges of characters, on single tokens and sets of single tokens. But,

```
ILLEGAL_ESCAPE  : ~LEGAL_ESCAPE ;
```

is unlikely what you were asking for.